# Flutter add activity to Android Manifest for ImageCropper

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-manifest

I am trying to implement [ImageCropper](https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper) inside my app. On Android I need to add some things to the Manifest according to the documentation but I can not make it work... This is my Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.memories">
<!-- Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
     to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
-->
<application>
    <activity>         
    android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"             
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"             
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

But this crashes with this error:

> E/AndroidRuntime( 9936):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 9936):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 9936):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 9936):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 9936):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 9936): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
> E/AndroidRuntime( 9936):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:155)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 9936):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.success(MethodChannel.java:238)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 9936):    at vn.hunghd.flutter.plugins.imagecropper.ImageCropperDelegate.onActivityResult(ImageCropperDelegate.java:106)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 9936):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry$FlutterEngineActivityPluginBinding.onActivityResult(FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.java:739)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 9936):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.onActivityResult(FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.java:426)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 9936):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onActivityResult(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:677)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 9936):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onActivityResult(FlutterActivity.java:624)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 9936):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8310)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 9936):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5008)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 9936):    ... 11 more
> I/Process ( 9936): Sending signal. PID: 9936 SIG: 9

What am I missing here? What is the correct way to add the `activities`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aaah... I changed the wrong `manifest`... it is important to change the **main**:

> /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in you **AndroidMainfest**. May be you are missing Launcher Activity in application level.

```
 <application
            android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
            android:label="example"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
            <meta-data
                android:name="flutterEmbedding"
                android:value="2" />
            <activity
                android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
  </application>
```